# Yahoo Finance Commodity Stock Quote PHP

Tags: php, xml, function, web-crawler, yahoo

Currently I'm trying to get the stock quote and change of a commodity from Yahoo Finance. For some reason commodity symbols aren't working, but regular stock quotes are.

Here is my code...

```
function getQuote($symbol) 
{

 $symbol  = urlencode( trim( substr(strip_tags($symbol),0,7) ) ); 
 $yahooCSV = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$symbol&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgvpnbaejkr&o=t";

 $csv = fopen($yahooCSV,"r");

 if($csv) 
 {
  list($quote['symbol'], $quote['last'], $quote['date'], $quote['timestamp'], $quote['change'], $quote['open'],
    $quote['high'], $quote['low'], $quote['volume'], $quote['previousClose'], $quote['name'], $quote['bid'],
    $quote['ask'], $quote['eps'], $quote['YearLow'], $quote['YearHigh'], $quote['PE']) = fgetcsv($csv, ','); 

  fclose($csv);

  return $quote; 
 } 
 else 
 {
  return false;
 }
}

getQuote("CLG12%2ENYM"); //this is the stock symbol
```

The results return 0.00 and N/A. As you can see I did do the symbol with the period escaped. I also tried this CLG12.NYM as the symbol, but that didn't work either.

**How can I get results from the commodities?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your URL Encoding for the $symbol. If you comment the URL encode line at the beginning of the function if will work fine.